# Making integer from file into (x,y,z) format (Python)

Tags: python, file-io

So I really need help on this lesson. The question I am unsure about is to make a function named smallest() to open a file called datanums.txt and make each line only display the lowest number.

Datanums.txt file:

```
6,3,5
4,4,8
3,7,2
1,8,9
9,0,6
```

What it should display:

```
3
4
2
1
0
```

The problem is that I need to get the lines of the txt file formatted into (x, y, z). Can someone please help?

My question is:
How do I define x, y, z ???

My code:

```
def smallest(x, y, z):

    with open('datanums.txt','r') as a:
        a.split().format(x, y, z)
        smallestNumber = sorted((x, y, z))[0]

        return smallestNumber

print smallest(x, y, z)
```

Comment: What have you tried, what doesn't work, what error you get ? This is not a forum to make people solve your homework.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza the error I get is that 3 arguments are needed on the print statement. And I do not know how to convert the file into (x,y,z) format.

Comment: Please don't vandalise your own questions. The answers may come in useful for someone else later on, not just yourself, and that requires the question stay in line with the answers!

Answer (score 5):

Since this is an assignment, I shouldn't give you a complete answer you can just copy and paste. So, take the following points:

- Your code is a good start, but obviously needs functionality
- After you open the file, you need to read line (hint, hint) by line.
- Then you need to turn that line into a list, for instance, use `split(',')`
- Trim and parse to int each entry
- find the `min()`
- `print` each of the resulting numbers.

Comment: This, basically. I like that way of giving hints. For more information, read the documentation (as well as the course material) on all of this. An interactive interpreter and the ``dir`` and ``help`` functions are your best friends.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you break this down into smaller tasks:

1. Read a line from the file.
2. Parse the line of text into 3 numbers.
3. Find the smallest number out of 3 numbers.
4. Print the result.
5. Make a loop that repeats steps 1-4 through the file.

Which of these steps do you know how to do? Which of these steps do you need help with? For the later, please come back with more questions.

Comment: I need help with 1 and 2.

Comment: @user3059711 Search `python read file line by line` and/or `python split text on delimiter`?

Answer (score 0):

The interesting part of your assignment is finding the minimum values.

Here is help with the data acquisition step:

```
with open('datanums.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y, z = f.rstrip().split(',')
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
        z = int(z)
        ...
```